# having troubles using stateparams with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, routes

nHello,

I am trying to use parameters in my router as follows :

my url call in my html file:

```
<a href="#/itemlist/{{hikelist.id}}">Edit</a>
```

And my router :

```
packApp
    .config(['$routeProvider', '$httpProvider', '$translateProvider', '$stateParams',
        function ($routeProvider, $httpProvider, $translateProvider, $stateParams) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/itemlist/:listId', {
                    templateUrl: 'views/itemlists.html',
                    controller: 'ItemlistController',
                    resolve:{
                        resolvedHikelist: ['Hikelist', function (Hikelist,$stateParams) {
                            return Itemlist.get({id: $stateParams.listId});
                        }]
                    }
                })
        }]);
```

But when i run my app, I have this error :

> Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $stateParams

Do you know where it can come from?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You have included or using both `ui-router` and angularjs standard $route service which are incompatible as both do the same thing. You would have to choose one of them.

See documentation on [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router) to understand how routes are setup if you go the `ui-router` way.

Else look at `$routeProvider` documentation and use `$routeParams` instead of `$stateParams`

Update: Based on the comments, the issue is that `config` method cannot be injected with services but only provider, so you cannot inject `$routeParams` in `.config` method so remove from there.

If you want to inject routeparams use

```
resolvedHikelist: ['Hikelist','$routeParams', function (Hikelist,$routeParams) {
                            return Itemlist.get({id: $routeParams.listId});
                        }]
```

Comment: Ok,I want to use routeProvider and $routeParams, but I m getting the same error : Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: $routeParams. I don't understand what's wrong in that injection.

Comment: You need to include the `ngRoute` module as dependency when you declare your app like `app = angular.module("packApp", ["ngRoute"`

Comment: Also make sure you included `angular-route.js` in your scripts. See documenation http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute

Comment: I ve cheked, it's all well configured, my routes worked perfectly until I added this routeParams stuff, which I need.

Comment: I ve trie on a blank angular project, it's the same. If i add $routeParams in my dependencies, I have the same problem : unknown provider.

Comment: That doesn't crash anymore, thanks a lot. But $routeParams.listId is undefined here. It works well if I do my 'Itemlist.get({id: $routeParams.listId})' in the controller called by this route. If it appears it's not possible to do it in my route, I ll do it in the controller.

Comment: it turns out that routeparams doesn't seem to be resolved at this time. Using $route.current.params works fine though. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

If you use $stateParams in ItemlistController don't forget to inject it to that controller as well.